# Find all zips, and unzip in place - Unix

Tags: shell, unix, find, zip, unzip

I have been trying for some time and believe I am fairly close to this, but I am fairly new to Unix so have been finding this difficult.

I have a folder, containing many folders, some of which have zip files in them, some which don't. I am trying to unzip all of the zip files in any sub directories in place.

For example I have:

files/A/something.java

files/B/somezipfile.zip

files/C/someotherfile.zip

files/D/AnotherZipFile.zip

I would like to unzip them (assuming the zips contain just .java files), to have a result like:
files/A/something.java

files/B/javafile.java

files/C/someotherfilefromzip.java

files/D/Anotherfile.java

I don't mind if the ZIP files remain or are deleted after unzipping, either is fine.

What I have tried so far.

1. I expected I could use piping, which I am new to, like this:

   ```
    find . -name *.zip | unzip
   ```

   This doesn't work.
2. I spent some time searching, the closest I got using a solution online is:

   ```
    find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip '{}' ';'
   ```

   This unzips, but unzips them into the current working directory, I wanted them to unzip in place. I also don't understand this command which I would like to as I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d `dirname {}` {}' ';'
```

This command looks in current directory and in its subdirectories recursively for files with names matching `*.zip` pattern.  For file found it executes command `sh` with two parameters:

```
-c
```

and

```
unzip -d `dirname <filename>` <filename>
```

Where `<filename>` is name of file that was found.  Command `sh` is Unix shell interpreter.  Option `-c` tells shell that next argument should be interpreted as shell script.  So shell interprets the following script:

```
unzip -d `dirname <filename>` <filename>
```

Before running `unzip` shell expands the command, by doing various substitutions.  In this particular example it substitutes

```
`dirname <filename>`
```

with output of command `dirname <filename>` which actually outputs directory name where file is placed.  So, if file name is `./a/b/c/d.zip`, shell will run `unzip` like this:

```
unzip -d ./a/b/c ./a/b/c/d.zip
```

In case you ZIP file names or directory names have spaces, use this:

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "`dirname \"{}\"`" "{}"' ';'
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer, any chance you could (very quickly) help me understand it? The bit I am confused about it the need for -exec and the {} marks.

Comment: I seem to have a problem if there is a space in the zips file name, is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: @NutterzUK Yes, this is easy to fix.  Just need to add quotes.  See my last addition to the answer.

Answer (score 44):

Use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, which runs the command in the directory where the file is found, not the directory you run `find` from.

```
find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip '{}' ';'
```

Comment: Worked fantastically.  Do you mind explaining what the `'{}' does (filename placeholder?) and why the `';'` needs to be a separate quote? Thanks!

Comment: {} means the current file you are  operating on

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -name '*.zip' | xargs -n1 unzip
```

Comment: this seems unable to handle options in `unzip`, e.g., `find . -name '*.zip' | xargs -n1 unzip -q` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the files contained in every `foo/bar.zip` file to be extracted under a `foo/bar/` directory.

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "`dirname \"{}\"`"/"`basename \"{}\" .zip`" "{}"' ';'
```

Comment: The quoting here can’t be reliable in general.