# Cygwin shell 'find' 'unzip' can't seem to get filtered off lines to not get passed to unzip

Tags: shell, unix, find

In Cygwin 64bit I have this command that does what I want it to:

```
$ find -name '*.zip' | wc -l
90
```

I try to pass the result to unzip, using the method from [Find all zips, and unzip in place - Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813130/find-all-zips-and-unzip-in-place-unix):

```
$ find -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -t '{}' ';' | wc -l
...random paths with the error continuing from "central" filename version...
17605 #?!?, why not 90 like before?
```

Appreciate some wisdom directed towards this little problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a different count because using `unzip -t` will test the archive extraction and will list each and every file inside `.zip` file thus you will be getting lot more output rather than just the name of `.zip` files.

You probably meant this `find` command:

```
find -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip '{}' ';' -print | wc -l
```

Comment: Not quite solved, but idea may be on the right track to the solution I envision: print only name.zip OK for each zip file at the input.Also can't upvote your answer, seems my reputation is kind of low :(.

Comment: On second thought your input makes sense of the problem I posed in the question, even though it doesn't fix my initial issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some more the documentation for unzip I found the second command in the following 2 that would solve my initial problem:

```
find -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -t '{}' ';'  #every file in every zip
find -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -tq '{}' ';' #one consolidated answer per zip
```